# Dependency injection of a child class when implementing an interface method that expects parent instance

Tags: php, oop

I have some doubts about PHP object-oriented programming.

Imagine this scenario:

```
abstract class A {}

class B extends A {}

interface C {

    public someMethod(A $a);
}
```

Is it possible, or any other workaround, to do this?

```
public class D implements C {

    public function someMethod(B $b) {
        // do something nice!
    }
}
```

Comment: `I have some doubts about PHP object-oriented programming.` Don't we all? :)

Comment: Check with `instanceof`?

Answer (score -1):

> Preconditions cannot be strengthened in a subtype.

You trying to ruin [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

You cannot implement it with PHP language constructions.

Also, check this example

```
abstract class A {}

class B extends A {}

abstract class C {
    public function __construct(A $a) {}
}

class D extends C {
    public function __construct(B $b) {
        // do something nice!
    }
}
```

It works only with `__construct`.